# include layout in Android is stretched

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, include

Got sample code that when is run on its own works fine.
But when I add it to my own project the lines of 'include' e.g:

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/chat_background_color"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<StickyListHeadersListView
    android:id="@+id/messages_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

<include layout="@layout/view_message_typing_status" />

<include layout="@layout/view_input_message_layout" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/emojicons_fragment"
    class="emoji.EmojiFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_emoji" /></LinearLayout>
```

strechs on the entire LinearLayout(screen).
In the layout file itself everything seems fine and is aligned to top of parent in RelativeLayout.

Why all the 'include's fail that way in my project but when i run the exact same layouts in the original project it works fine?

Using Android Studio.

The views themselfs are in a RelativeLayout with a height limit of 50dp.

When i add the 50dp height defenition to the include it seems to be fine, but I'd like to know how this works to understand better the cause of the problem.

Comment: You will need to show us the entire XML file that the include is called from to help you out fully but just as a hint the containing view that it is being included into is probably acting on the view_status contents.  That's why it works fine when on its own but different when loaded into another (parent) view.

Comment: Added with more details below code

Comment: Please include the full XML layout files for the view so we can analyze and/or reproduce the problem.

You could also show the demo project so we can compare those two.

Comment: @arnfada Hi, this issue is with every include statement in every file(there are many different views and include).
The xml itself looks like a normal layout xml of a view, relativelayout and within it some controls, nothing special.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple sources stating that if you don't override both the `layout_width` and `layout_height` in the include statement that other things "won't work". [Google developers](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2863) don't really view it as an issue and it always feels more like a workaround than anything else.  But in any case if you declare width and height in your include than everything should work as expected.